# Reference selection in Vim command mode to pass on to terminal

Tags: vim

Is there something like `%` (that represents the whole buffer in `Vim command line`) for the current selection, so that I can do something like: `:# sort` (Imagine `#` represents the selection).

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed to mention that I am requesting for a way to operate on **block selections** not on ordinary selections that can be operated using ranges `'<,'>`.

Comment: Did you notice the `'<,'>` that Vim inserted automatically after the `:`? Read `:help range`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Example:

```
:'<,'>!sort
```

- The range `:'<,'>` represents the visually selected lines.
- `:*` is shorthand for `:'<,'>`
- If you hit `:` while in visual mode it will start the command with `'<,'>`

For more help see:

```
:h '<
:h v_:
:h range
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the marks `'<` and `'>`:

```
:'<,'>sort
```

If you just select a few lines and hit <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the command line these marks should appear automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already remarked, the visual selection is represented by the `'<,'>` *range* (there's also the `:*` short form). However, **as all ranges, this always covers entire lines**, even if the selection is only characters or a block.

Most Ex commands (like `:sort`) only operate on full lines, for `:substitute`, you can limit the effects to the visual selection by including the special `\%V` atom in the search pattern, cp. `:help /\%V`.

The idea to make Ex commands handle blockwise selections is old, but unlikely to be tackled any time soon.